# How to distinguish between folders and prefixes in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

According to [Difference between prefixes and nested folders in Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-prefix-nested-folders-difference/) folders and prefixes are distinct entities. It states folders can only be created via the AWS Console. Since all files in my bucket are created through the boto3 module, they are expected to only create prefixes rather than folders. However, they get reported as folders in the web UI. Is there a way for me to distinguished between these two entities via either the UI or programmatically? The docs say I should see a distinct object, but I'm not sure if the object I see is just a matter of representation of the prefix for the UI.
A related question (that may or may not warrant a different SO question) is whether or not files inside a folder are considered to have different prefixes for determining rate limits.
The only clue I get from the doc is this:

> Note: The folder structure might not indicate any partitioned prefixes that support request rates.

However, I'm not sure how to interpret this "might" here. I would think it sometimes does and sometimes does not apply independent rate limits, and in that case I'd need to know when it does and when it doesn't somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon S3 is a 'flat' object storage service. It does not use folders.

However, as you point out, users can create folders in the S3 management console. Doing so actually creates a **zero-length object with the same name as the folde**r. This forces the folder to appear in the console (and as a Common Prefix) even if there are no objects 'inside' the folder.

The Key (filename) of an object contains the full path of the object. When calling `ListObjects()` and specifying a delimiter (eg `/`), S3 will return **a list of Common Prefixes** that can be considered the equivalent of a folder or directory. This allows programs and the console to navigate the objects in a hierarchical-like pattern.

To **distinguish between a Folder created in the S3 management console and a Common Prefix**, look for a zero-length object with a Key equal to the full path of the folder.

Discussions about **rate limits** are only relevant for situations where massive quantities of queries are performed against a given Amazon S3 bucket. The vast majority of S3 users will never be impacted by rate limits. Amazon S3 does some magical stuff in the background to partition buckets based on size and usage patterns (hence the comment about 'partitioned prefixes') but this partitioning is invisible to AWS customers. The Note about request rates is basically saying that a folder or Common Prefix does not indicate that the bucket has necessarily been partitioned at that point.

Comment: How massive. Let's say 8 10GB files under the same prefix for download, with no visibility (that I know of) of the request size because I use boto3. Is it that order or magnitude? In particular I'm having issues with corrupted downloads for files the awscli is able to download correctly and there's a reported bug about incomplete downloads not being properly reported, so one hypothesis was hitting rate limits.

Comment: Also, minor question to know if I got it right. This new "folder" object woud be equivalent to just creating an empty '/' object under the same prefix, right?

Comment: Throughput is listed in: [Resolve Throttling on Your Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-request-limit-avoid-throttling/) This involves massive quantities of parallel requests (5500 per second), which is unlikely to be your situation. If you are having a problem with downloads, please create a new Question with full details. Yes to the empty object.

Comment: My main problem is that I'm not having enough visibility on what's failing, the failure is intermittent (repeats itself if attempted soon enough, but after a while it resolves) and the code I work on is proprietary, so working on a case I can post is not trivial. I think it's in the download, but the only sign of that being the case is that decompression by my service fails while decompression by an independent download works.